# What are some practical applications of the formfeed character in R source code?

Tags: r, ascii, special-characters, delimiter

The manuals [[3](https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html)], including the *R Language Definition* [1] and *Writing R Extensions* [2] state "whitespace characters [including] formfeeds... serve to delimit tokens in case of ambiguity" [1] and "Only ASCII characters [including] formfeed... should be used in code files" [2].

When might the use of formfeed in sourcecode be advantageous?

How do typical text editors interpret formfeed?

I typically use Vim. Formfeed seems to appear as `^L`, and does not seem to have an effect analogous to form feed on a printer.

In the RGui (R 3.5.3), `cat` places a box-shaped character when formfeed is encountered (using Courier New font on Windows 10).

[1] R Core Team (2016-06-21) R Language Definition, v3.3.1

[2] R Core Team (2019-07-05) Writing R Extensions, v3.6.1

[3] https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html

Comment: I use them as "sections" of long scripts. Since I use emacs/ess, which allows me to use `C-x [` and `C-x ]` to jump to the previous/next formfeed (when in the first column). I'm guessing there are similar mechanisms in other editors, though I can't speak for them. Since they are ignored by the R interpreter, it's innocent enough keeping them in the code with no real consequence.

Comment: (I don't suggest that the use as section breaks in long scripts is advisable for long-*term* projects, mostly just for scratch code. For larger or more-formal projects,  it is typically better to use perhaps a more formal structure, whether individual files, org-mode (emacs), rmarkdown sections/subsections, etc.)

Comment: In Rstudio, `cat('\f')` clears the console